# Can you cancel a Vulkan execution?

Tags: vulkan

I have a Vulkan Compute Shader than can take a second or two to do its work. If the user changes parameters whilst that's happening, I don't want there to be lag, I want the calculations to abort and restart with the new data. Is it possible to cancel a work-in-progress submitted command buffer?

I did consider checking an abort flag whilst waiting for the fence to complete. But that doesn't clear the queue which will still be executing the shader(s).

Comment: "*I have a Vulkan Compute Shader than can take a second or two to do its work.*" If this is all done in a single dispatch call, be aware that some GPUs/OS will just kill your application if it monopolizes the GPU for that long. So if it is one dispatch, it's really important to break it up into smaller dispatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not supported at the moment, but I submitted a suggestion to that effect: [KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/1468](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues/1468)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot cancel a queue submission.

If you can split apart the workload into multiple submissions (which for something that takes multiple seconds you probably can) you can instead parcel it out little bits at a time.

That way when the user changes the parameters you can stop submitting work to the gpu and start over with the new parameters.